# My AppleID is suddenly not being accepted for Application Loader

Tags: ios11, application-loader, xcode8.2

I used my credentials for create 3 api's in morning but when in noon I tried to create 4th one, application loader fire a message "The application account information was incorrect". I tried to login again button getting same error. My AppleId and Password are correct because I am using same account for login in developer account.

I tried to close loader thrice but hand is still empty.Waiting for your precious suggestion.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/system-status/ "iTunes Connect - 1 Issue, 
Issue: Today, 3:45 PM - ongoing
Some users are affected
Users are experiencing a problem with this service."

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Answer:**

```
It's working fine for me now, please try again now
```

[image]

[image]

**Obsolete Answer:**

Based on this 
https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

and this https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/90725

It seems that service is down to few users, therefore, keep patience and wait until the issue is resolved by Apple team.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue which started about 90 minutes ago. Earlier this morning I had success uploading.
Updated 29 Oct. 0635Z back end services are working for me now.

Comment: Same issue for me. I could upload two apps successfully this morning, but I now receive account information errors from iTunes Connect (with -20207 error code).